# iOS: How to make a loop that runs random action each time, one after another

Tags: objective-c

I am making game where random animals will emerge from every direction (up, down, left, right). There'll be an animal emerge from one side, it will move to the opposite side, and after that one's gone, another animal will emerge from another random direction. My problem is when I run it, all the animals emerge simultaneously from all directions, not one by one. It also moves in a blinking manner in which it moves a little bit, and then another one emerge from another direction moving a little bit. How do I make a it go one by one? After one animal done moving across the screen, then another will emerge.

```
-(void)gameplay {

int randomNumber;
NSString *numberString;
NSArray *numberArray;

numberArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];
randomNumber = arc4random()%[numberArray count];
numberString = [numberArray objectAtIndex:randomNumber];

direction = [numberString intValue];

if (direction == 1) {
    if (animalKanan.center.x > -95) {
    animalKanan.hidden = NO;
    animalKanan.center = CGPointMake(animalKanan.center.x - 10, animalKanan.center.y);
    animalKiri.hidden = YES;
    animalKiri.center = animalKiri.center;
    animalBelakang.hidden = YES;
    animalBelakang.center = animalBelakang.center;
    animalDepan.hidden = YES;
    animalDepan.center = animalDepan.center;

   }
 }

if (direction == 2) {
    if (animalKiri.center.x < 365) {
    animalKiri.hidden = NO;
    animalKiri.center = CGPointMake(animalKiri.center.x + 10, animalKiri.center.y);
    animalKanan.hidden = YES;
    animalKanan.center = animalKanan.center;
    animalBelakang.hidden = YES;
    animalBelakang.center = animalBelakang.center;
    animalDepan.hidden = YES;
    animalDepan.center = animalDepan.center;
    }
}


if (direction == 3) {
    if (animalBelakang.center.y < 530) {
    animalBelakang.hidden = NO;
    animalBelakang.center = CGPointMake(animalBelakang.center.x, animalBelakang.center.y + 10);
    animalKiri.hidden = YES;
    animalKiri.center = animalKiri.center;
    animalKanan.hidden = YES;
    animalKanan.center = animalKanan.center;
    animalDepan.hidden = YES;
    animalDepan.center = animalDepan.center;
    }
}

if (direction == 4) {
    if (animalDepan.center.y > -5) {
    animalDepan.hidden = NO;
    animalDepan.center = CGPointMake(animalDepan.center.x, animalDepan.center.y - 10);
    animalKiri.hidden = YES;
    animalKiri.center = animalKiri.center;
    animalBelakang.hidden = YES;
    animalBelakang.center = animalBelakang.center;
    animalKanan.hidden = YES;
    animalKanan.center = animalKanan.center;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Are you using [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html)? If not, do so. If yes, are you using [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/)? If not do so. `SKAction` has a really useful method called `repeatActionForever:` which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a [game loop](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html). The idea is that you need to update the state of the game, display it to the user, and then get user input over and over again. So it would look something like this:

```
while (!gameOver)
{
    gameOver = [game updateGameState];
    [game draw];
    [game getUserInput];
}
```

In this scenario, your `-gamePlay` method would be part of `-updateGameState`.

One issue with your `-gamePlay` method is that you're changing all the state at once. If I understand what you've written correctly, you only ever want 1 animal coming out at a time, and you also want to advance the location of that animal on each frame. These are 2 separate tasks, so I'd break them into 2 methods. Maybe something like:

```
- (Animal*)getCurrentAnimal
{
    // If the current animal has moved off the board, release another one
    if ([_currentAnimal isBeyondEdge])
    {
        // Release it
        [_currentAnimal release];
        // Create a new one
        _currentAnimal = [self makeNewRandomAnimal];
    }

    return _currentAnimal;
}
```

and:

```
- (void)advanceAnimal:(Animal)animal
{
    [animal updatePosition];
}
```

where the `-updatePosition` method does the job of moving the animal. For one type of animal, that will mean:

```
- (void)updatePosition
{
    _center.x += 10.0;
}
```

While a different animal might have:

```
- (void)updatePosition
{
    _center.y -= 10.0;
}
```

And the `-makeNewRandomAnimal` method might look like this:

```
- (Animal*)makeNewRandomAnimal
{
    int randomNum = arc4random() % kMaxNumAnimals;
    switch (randomNum)
    {
        case 0: 
            return [[Tiger alloc] init];
        break;

        case 1: 
            return [[Lion alloc] init];
        break;

        // and whatever other animals you need

        default:
            return [[Duck alloc] init];
        break;
    }
}
```

In this scenario, `Animal` is your base class, and it contains the properties that all animals share, such as whether they are hidden, what their position is, maybe a property like maximum speed, or whatever you need for your game. If they all have the same properties (but different values for those properties), you don't need to subclass them - just create different instances with the appropriate properties. But if some animals have properties that other animals don't, then you probably want to subclass them.

Your `-draw` method will then draw the world - the animal, the player's character, and anything else appropriate. The `getUserInput` method will check if the user is pressing a key, a mouse (on a computer) or the screen (on a phone or tablet), etc.

This way you can systematically move things around and have them react to the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

How is gameplay method called? Perhaps the moves are too fast?

You should make your animal move **relative to elapsed time** (you can call gameplay using `CADisplayLink` to be linked to framerate, or using `NSTimer` - to be called regularly - or make it evaluates the elapsed time since its last call). Then, evaluate your x moves or y moves relative to a speed (in pixels/sec) times elapsed time in seconds.

You should have a property in your object using gameplay: `NSDate *lastCall;`

In gameplay:

```
{
    if( !lastCall )
    lastCall = [[NSDate date] retain];
    NSDate now = [NSDate date];

    // dt = elapsed time since last call
    NSTimeInterval dt = [now timeIntervaleSinceDate:lastCall];
    ...
    animalKanan.center = CGPointMake(animalKanan.center.x - 10 * dt, animalKanan.center.y);
    ...
    [lastCall release]; // free lastCall value
    lastCall = [now retain];
}
```

Then, the speed of your objects/animals is **relative to elapsed time** and not the execution speed of your device.